# Problem with C++ standard container not inserting new values

Tags: c++, std

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<string,set<int>> map;
    set<int> s;
    s.insert(1);
    s.insert(2);s.insert(3);
    map.insert(make_pair("Screen1",s));
    for(auto it : map)
    {
        cout<<it.first<<endl;
        it.second.insert(5);
    }
    for (auto i : map["Screen1"])
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

In the above stated code I am trying to insert a value 5 in the set inside the map. but
**it.second.insert(5);** doesnot do the trick

here is the output that i am getting

```
Screen1
1
2
3
```

Comment: Please remove `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` from your code.

Comment: [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux those all may be good advice, but do they have any bearing on the problem presented here?

Comment: @MarkRansom No, it is just recommended reading that, based shown in the code provided, would benefit them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for(auto it : map)
```

the variable `it` is a copy of every element in `map`, so modifying `it` doesn't modify `map`.

If you want to modify the elements, you need to do:

```
for(auto &it : map)
```

so that `it` is a reference to every element in `map`.

Comment: If this is the case, how is it that `it` has a member `second`?

Comment: @MarkRansom A copy still has the same type, which has the same members.  It just doesn't refer to the same object.

Comment: So you're saying a copy of an iterator doesn't refer to the same object as the original iterator?  I find that hard to believe.

Comment: No, I think you're misunderstanding what `it` is. It's not an iterator, but the actual element in the container (or a copy of it). A copy of an iterator *would* refer to the same object as the original iterator, just like a pointer.

Comment: Yes, but the item in the question didn't include a `second` member.  Thus my question.  If things are as you say, it shouldn't have compiled.

Comment: Sure it does. The elements of a `map` are essentially `pair`s which have a `second` member.

Comment: @MarkRansom `it` is a `std::pair<const std::string, std::set<int, int>>`. The loop does not expose any iterators. In the case without a reference, the key and the entire `std::set` that is the value are copied to the pair.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you and cigien for pounding into my head what should have been obvious.